# Fastest way to convert Vector to QJsonArray?

Tags: c++, qt, vector, move, qjson

Currently, I am iterating through a vector in order to convert it to a QJsonArray:

```cpp
QJsonArray toJson(const std::vector<unsigned short>& myVec) {
    QJsonArray result;
    for(auto i = myVec.begin(); i != myVec.end(); i++) {
        result.push_back((*i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, this causes a small lag spike in my program. Is there an alternative method to receive a QJsonArray with the data from a vector? (It doesn't need to be a deep copy.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid there is no faster way than the one you designed. `QJsonArray` consists of `QJsonValue` values, that can encapsulate native values of different types: `Null`, `Bool`, `Double`, `String`, ..., `Undefined`. But `std::vector` consists of values of one only type. Therefore each value of a vector should be converted to `QJsonValue` individually, and there is no faster way like `memcopy`.

In any case you may shorten your function.

```
QJsonArray toJson(const std::vector<unsigned short>& myVec) {
    QJsonArray result;
    std::copy (myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ah, so the slowness is due to the fact that each value needs to be converted to a QJsonValue?

Comment: Exactly. Moreover `QJsonArray` API does not provide `emplace_back` that would be faster than `push_back`.

Comment: One possible area for optimization could be the memory allocation. `QJsonArray` doesn't have a way to "reserve" N elements at once, but `QVariantList` does - and QJsonArray has a somewhat optimized static function `QJsonAray::fromVariantList`. Worth testing at least.